# RLP encoding on tezos

Tags: node, encoding

How can we achieve rlp encoding on tezos ?
Does smartpy or any other language supports rlp encoding on tezos ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airgap is working on an inter blockchain communication protocol which uses RLP as data encoding.

You can find the RLP encoding/decoding at: [RLP](https://github.com/airgap-it/ibcf/blob/main/contracts/tezos/utils/utils.py)

It is still a work in progress.

Comment: Do you know if there is any ETA for this ?

Comment: It should be available on (Ghostnet <-> Goerli) next month. About the RLP encoding/decoding, it is already usable.